# Transit through Manchester

Tags: usa, uk, manchester

I am a Nigerian citizen with a student stay permit in Italy and I am flying to the US through Manchester. I will arrive Manchester on the 9th by 14pm and the continued flight is on the 10th by 11 am.

Do I need a transit visa? Will I go through boarder control? Can I go outside and return seeing that I have a long wait before the continued flight?

Comment: Are you otherwise admissible to the UK?

Comment: Yes from the explanation, i believe I do not need the transit visa.